# Adding resize functionality to an element in angular

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular

I am adding a resize functionality following a codepen example
mentioned in the comments using MARGIN=4 (here I was not able to add the codepen link)
The codepen was the best working example which I could find.

Have added 4 elements on all the 4 edges of the box.

I Have added hostlisteners to pointerdown , pointermove and pointerup but I am stuck with executing the **animate()** function present in Resizable directive.

In the directive the code has mainly 3 functions doing all the calculations **onDown()** , **calc(e)**, **animate()**

```
import { Directive,
         ElementRef,
         HostListener } from '@angular/core';
import { DraggableDirective } from './draggable.directive';

@Directive({
 selector: '[appResizable]' // Attribute selector
})

export class ResizableDirective extends DraggableDirective{

constructor(public element:ElementRef){
super(element);
}

minWidth = 60;
minHeight = 40;
// Thresholds
MARGINS = 4;

//End Of whats configurable
clicked = null;
public onRightEdge; onBottomEdge; onLeftEdge; onTopEdge;
public b; x; y;

redraw = false;
e;
clickedDragging = false;

ngOnInit(){
 this.animate() 
}

@HostListener('dragStart', ['$event'])
 onDragStart(e:PointerEvent): void{
 this.clickedDragging = true;
 this.onDown(e);
 e.preventDefault();
 }

@HostListener('dragMove', ['$event'])
  onDragMove(ee): void{
   if (!this.dragging || ee.pointerId !== this.pointerId) {
    return;
   }
   if((<HTMLElement>event.srcElement).id === ('side-top')){
   this.onMove(ee);
   ee.preventDefault();
   }
 }

 @HostListener('dragEnd', ['$event'])
     ondragend(ev): void{
     this.onUp(ev);
  }

onMove(ee){
    if (!this.dragging || ee.pointerId !== this.pointerId) {
     return;
   }
   if(this.clickedDragging){
     this.calc(ee);
     this.e = ee;
     this.redraw = true;
    }
   }

onDown(e){
    this.calc(e);

    let isResizing = this.onRightEdge || this.onBottomEdge || 
                     this.onLeftEdge || this.onTopEdge;

    this.clicked = {
      x: this.x,
      y: this.y,
      cx: e.clientX,
      cy: e.clientY,
      w: this.b.width,
      h: this.b.height,
      isResizing: isResizing,
      onRightEdge: this.onRightEdge,
      onBottomEdge: this.onBottomEdge,
      onLeftEdge: this.onLeftEdge,
      onTopEdge: this.onTopEdge,
   }

 }

calc(e){
   this.b = this.element.nativeElement.getBoundingClientRect();
   this.x = e.clientX - this.b.left;
   this.y = e.clientY - this.b.top;

   this.onRightEdge = this.x >= this.b.width - this.MARGINS;
   this.onBottomEdge = this.y >= this.b.height - this.MARGINS;
   this.onLeftEdge = this.x < this.MARGINS;
   this.onTopEdge = this.y < this.MARGINS;
  }

animate(){
  requestAnimationFrame(this.animate);
  if(!this.redraw)return;
  this.redraw = false;

  if(this.clicked && this.clicked.isResizing){

    if(this.clicked.onRightEdge){ 
      this.element.nativeElement.style.width = Math.max(this.x, 
      this.minWidth) + 'px';
    }

   if(this.clicked.onBottomEdge){
       this.element.nativeElement.style.height = Math.max(this.y, 
       this.minHeight) + 'px';
    }

   if(this.clicked.onLeftEdge){
     let currentWidth = Math.max(this.clicked.cx - 
         this.e.clientX + this.clicked.w, this.minWidth);

     if(currentWidth > this.minWidth){
      this.element.nativeElement.style.width = currentWidth + 'px';
      this.element.nativeElement.style.left = this.e.clientX + 'px';
     }
    }

    if (this.clicked.onTopEdge) {
     var currentHeight = Math.max(this.clicked.cy - 
                                  this.e.clientY  +
                                   this.clicked.h, this.minHeight);
     if (currentHeight > this.minHeight) {
      this.element.nativeElement.style.height = currentHeight + 'px';
      this.element.nativeElement.style.top = this.e.clientY + 'px'; 
     }
    }

  return;
 }
}

onUp(ev) {
   this.calc(ev);
   this.clicked = null;
   }  
}
```

HTML snippet on which directive has been applied

```
<div class="box" *ngFor="let box of dropzone1" appDroppable (dragStart)="currentBox = box" appMovable>
    {{ box.dis }}

    <div class="side side-h" id="side-top" (dragStart)=(e) (dragMove)=(e) (dragEnd)=(e) appResizable></div>
    <div class="side side-v" id="side-right" (click)="clcikme(e)" ></div>
    <div class="side side-h" id="side-bottom" (click)="clcikme(e)"></div>
    <div class="side side-v" id="side-left" (click)="clcikme(e)"></div>
</div>
```

In the codepen example for b

```
this.b = this.element.nativeElement.getBoundingClientRect();
```

the whole element has been taken which I'll also have to do, in my case I have the border on which the directive is there

I am attaching a working stackblitz the resizable directive is present in draggable folder and used in hello component
In the stackblitz console logging of pointerdown, pointermove can also be seen.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-pcpev1?file=src/app/hello.component.html

Error in console animate of undefined

Please refer to the codepen example from the comments.

**Update**

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-pcpev1?file=src%2Fapp%2Fhello.component.html

Comment: codepen link https://codepen.io/zz85/pen/gbOoVP

Comment: Have you tried using the angular animations api ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sorry I can't fix your code because it's a mess, you just do this completely wrong, you just did two approaches I suggest in one code. Also you're leaking resize internals outside of directive, the divs need to be hidden, outside you only should use `resize` attribute and everything should be created inside directive.

Here, this is started for one top side:

```
@Directive({
    selector: '[resize]'
})
class Resizable implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
    private nodes: HtmlElement[] = [];
    private data: {x: number, y: number, rect: ClientRect, direction: string};
    constructor(@Inject(ElementRef) private element: ElementRef) {
        this.mousemove = this.mousemove.bind(this);
        this.mouseup = this.mouseup.bind(this);
    }
    mousemove(e) {
        if (this.data) {
            switch(this.data.direction) {
                case 'top':
                    var offset = this.data.y - e.clientY;
                    var height = this.data.rect.height;
                    var top = this.data.rect.top;
                    var style = this.element.nativeElement.style;
                    style.height = height + offset + 'px';
                    style.top = top - offset + 'px';
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
    ngOnInit() {
        var node = document.createElement('div');
        node.classList.add('border-top', 'border');
        this.element.nativeElement.appendChild(node);
        this.nodes.push(node);
        window.addEventListener('mousemove', this.mousemove);
        window.addEventListener('mouseup', this.mouseup);
    }
    @HostListener('mousedown', ['$event'])
    mousedown(e) {
        if (e.target.classList.contains('border')) {
            var rect = this.element.nativeElement.getBoundingClientRect();
            this.data = {
                x: e.clientX,
                y: e.clientY,
                rect,
                direction: e.target.className.match(/border-([^ ]+)/)[1]
            };
            e.preventDefault();
        } else {
            delete this.data;
        }
    }
    mouseup(e) {
         delete this.data;
    }
    ngOnDestroy() {
        this.nodes.forEach(n => n.remove());
        window.removeEventListener('mousemove', this.mousemove);
        window.removeEventListener('mouseup', this.mouseup);
    }
}
```

here is [CodePen demo](https://codepen.io/jcubic/pen/wvwJNqQ)

Comment: Thanks alot , how can I apply this to rest of the 3 sides

Comment: @Enthu You need to create divs for each side (with class border-xxx) create CSS that will move element to the side and do similar calculation inside `switch(this.data.direction) {`, with `bottom`, `right`, and `left`

Comment: Thanksyou very much , I'll implement and in case any issues I'll ask, thanks alot

Comment: @Enthu it have to be dragged if you want to change only one side. the left and top need to be changed when you resize by dragging top and left side.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/198496/discussion-between-jcubic-and-enthu).

Comment: the update is ,resizing is working :) ,but my dropzone area bounding directives are not working

Comment: It's hard to test your drag & drop because it's also broken, you're selecting text instead and you don't see dragging element. Now I can't even drag the item.

Comment: No, I mean nothing happens when you drag every demo you posted have the same issue, only when the cursor appear on dropzone it magically appear, this is not how drag & drop works you should see the box or special cursor element when you're dragging element.

Comment: ok yeah you are right , now I also recognized what your are saying is correct :) that I can take it up later , but for now if you could suggest how can I handle box not going out when I resize , the above issue , thanks

Comment: I had implemented resize functionality given by you but the boxes start moving out once I try to resize whereas ideally the boxes do not move out before the resize directive is applied , I had tried to put class checking of className === "border-top border" for all the borders in all the dragstart and dragmove events in Draggable , movable , droppable directives but still I am not able to contain the box within the grey area when I resize , the stackblitz link https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-pcpev1?file=src%2Fapp%2Fhello.component.html

Comment: I have also created a query related to this , https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57672828/directive-not-responding-due-to-same-mouse-events-applied-in-two-directives-on-s , if you can help it would be great

Comment: Brilliant, upvoted! I converted (most) of the code into my own directives without too much hassle (didn't do the draggable), and it works great. I'll jiggle the CSS a bit and throw a few config options in there, and release it into the wild as a package, it's a great little directive.