# Directive not responding due to same mouse events being used in multiple directives on same element

Tags: html, css, angular, angular-directive

I have a feature where box can be dragged and dropped into the grey area(Please refer to the stackblitz link)
Once the box is dragged and dropped , the box can only be moved within the grey area by clicking on the pink color of the box.

Resizing functionality has also been added, so the box can be resized.

Before resize directive was added the box can only be moved within grey area but after adding adding the resize directive when we resize, the box starts moving out of the grey area , the issue is the box should not move out of the grey area when resizing is done

Stackblitz link

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rgeq2p?file=src/app/hello.component.html

hello.component.html *[ has the box and directives applied on the box ]*

```
<div appMovableArea appDropzone (drop)="move(currentBox, dropzone1)">
<div *ngFor="let box of dropzone1"
      appDroppable
     (dragStart)="currentBox = box"
      appMovable
      resize>
    {{ box.dis }}
</div>
</div>
```

where the box has (dragStart) output event emitter which is bound to draggable directive([appDroppable + draggable] and  for the
move functionality appMovable, appMovableArea directives are there) .And the events are shared among directives using Droppable.service.ts

> The **(drop)** is an output event emitter applied on grey area using
>   **dropzone**[*appDropzone*] directive

```
import { Directive, ElementRef, EventEmitter, HostBinding, HostListener, 
    OnInit, Output, SkipSelf } from '@angular/core';
import { DroppableService } from './droppable.service';

@Directive({
     selector: '[appDropzone]',
     providers: [DroppableService]
    })
export class DropzoneDirective implements OnInit {

     @Output() drop = new EventEmitter<PointerEvent>();
     @Output() remove = new EventEmitter<PointerEvent>();
     private clientRect: ClientRect;

constructor(@SkipSelf() private allDroppableService: DroppableService,
              private innerDroppableService: DroppableService,
              private element: ElementRef) { }

ngOnInit(): void {
        this.allDroppableService.dragStart$.subscribe(() => 
        this.onDragStart());
        this.allDroppableService.dragEnd$.subscribe(event => 
        this.onDragEnd(event));

        this.allDroppableService.dragMove$.subscribe(event => {
          if (this.isEventInside(event)) {
        this.onPointerEnter();
      } else {
        this.onPointerLeave();
      }
     });
        this.innerDroppableService.dragStart$.subscribe(() => 
        this.onInnerDragStart());
        this.innerDroppableService.dragEnd$.subscribe(event => 
        this.onInnerDragEnd(event));
}

private onPointerEnter(): void {
     if (!this.activated) {
      return;
     }
     this.entered = true;
     }

private onPointerLeave(): void {
        if (!this.activated) {
         return;
      }
     this.entered = false;
     }

private onDragStart(): void {
       this.clientRect = this.element.nativeElement.getBoundingClientRect();
       this.activated = true;
      }

private onDragEnd(event: PointerEvent): void {
        if (!this.activated) {
         return;
      }
      if (this.entered) {
        this.drop.emit(event);
      }
     }

private onInnerDragStart() {
    this.activated = true;
    this.entered = true;
    }

private onInnerDragEnd(event: PointerEvent) {
    if (!this.entered) {
      this.remove.emit(event);
    }
  }

private isEventInside(event: PointerEvent) {
    return event.clientX >= this.clientRect.left &&
      event.clientX <= this.clientRect.right &&
      event.clientY >= this.clientRect.top &&
      event.clientY <= this.clientRect.bottom;
  }
}
```

> Then on the box **(dragStart)** output event emitter which is present in**draggable** directive[*appDraggable*]  which listens for pointerdown events

```
import { Directive, EventEmitter, HostBinding, HostListener, Output, 
ElementRef } from '@angular/core';
@Directive({
 selector: '[appDraggable],[appDroppable]'
})
export class DraggableDirective {
 @Output() dragStart = new EventEmitter<PointerEvent>();
 @Output() dragMove = new EventEmitter<PointerEvent>();
 @Output() dragEnd = new EventEmitter<PointerEvent>();

 constructor(public element: ElementRef) {}

 @HostListener('pointerdown', ['$event'])
   onPointerDown(event: PointerEvent): void {
    if (event.button !== 0) {
    return;
   }
   this.pointerId = event.pointerId;
   this.dragging = true;
   this.dragStart.emit(event); 
   }

 @HostListener('document:pointermove', ['$event'])
    onPointerMove(event: PointerEvent): void {
     if (!this.dragging || event.pointerId !== this.pointerId) {
     return;
    } 
    this.dragMove.emit(event);
    }

 @HostListener('document:pointercancel', ['$event'])
 @HostListener('document:pointerup', ['$event'])
     onPointerUp(event: PointerEvent): void {
    if (!this.dragging || event.pointerId !== this.pointerId) {
      return;
    }
    this.dragging = false;
    this.dragEnd.emit(event);
    }
   }
```

> **Movable** directive for maintaining move inside the grey area which in
>   turn uses calculation based from movable-area directive

```
import { Directive, ElementRef, HostBinding, HostListener, Input } from 
'@angular/core';
import { DraggableDirective } from './draggable.directive';
import { DomSanitizer, SafeStyle } from '@angular/platform-browser';

interface Position {
 x: number;
 y: number;
}

@Directive({
 selector: '[appMovable]'
})
export class MovableDirective extends DraggableDirective {
  @HostBinding('style.transform') get transform(): SafeStyle {
   return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustStyle(
  `translateX(${this.position.x}px) translateY(${this.position.y}px)`
  );
  }

  @HostBinding('class.movable') movable = true;
  position: Position = {x: 0, y: 0};
  private startPosition: Position;
  @Input('appMovableReset') reset = false;

constructor(private sanitizer: DomSanitizer, public element: ElementRef) {
   super(element);
 }

@HostListener('dragStart', ['$event'])
   onDragStart(event: PointerEvent) {
     this.startPosition = {
     x: event.clientX - this.position.x,
     y: event.clientY - this.position.y
 }
 }

@HostListener('dragMove', ['$event'])
   onDragMove(event: PointerEvent) {
    this.position.x = event.clientX - this.startPosition.x;
    this.position.y = event.clientY - this.startPosition.y;
 }

@HostListener('dragEnd', ['$event'])
   onDragEnd(event: PointerEvent) {
    if (this.reset) {
     this.position = {x: 0, y: 0};
 }
 }
}
```

The resize directive is also present in the stackblitz link.
And styles for resize directive are present in styles.css

Comment: @jcubic , please help

Comment: You can't prevent one mouse move from another mouse move on same element, try putting drag on parent and resize on child.

Comment: @Enthu what is the issue? I tried resizing and it still holds the boundaries

Comment: @NidhinJoseph , when we resize then the box starts moving and goes out of the grey area, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here is implementation of Drag&Drop directive, sorry can't fix your code because it's a mess same as resize:

**Directive**

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[draggable]'
})
class Draggable implements onInit {
    private element: HTMLElement;
    private handlerNode: HTMLElement;
    private data: {x: number, y: number};

    @Input('draggable')
    private handler: string;

    @HostListener('mousedown', ['$event'])
    mousedown(e) {
        if (e.target === this.handlerNode) {
            var rect = this.element.getBoundingClientRect();
            this.data = {
                x: e.clientX - rect.left,
                y: e.clientY - rect.top
            };
        } else {
            delete this.data;
        }
    }

    @HostListener('document:mouseup', ['$event'])
    mouseup(e) {
        delete this.data;
    }
    constructor(@Inject(ElementRef) element: ElementRef) {
        this.element = element.nativeElement;
    }
    ngOnInit() {
        this.element.classList.add('dragabble');
        this.handlerNode = this.element.querySelector(this.handler);
    }

    @HostListener('document:mousemove', ['$event'])
    onPointerMove(e: PointerEvent): void {
        if (this.data) {
            var x = e.clientX - this.data.x;
            var y = e.clientY - this.data.y;
            this.element.style.left = x + 'px';
            this.element.style.top = y + 'px';
        }
    }
}
```

**CSS**

```
.dragabble .handler {
    position: absolute;
    width: calc(100% - 12px);
    height: calc(100% - 12px);
    left: 6px;
    top: 6px;
}
```

**Template**:

```
<div [resize]="toggle" style="left: 100px; top: 50px"
     [draggable]="'.handler'">
  <div class="handler">xxx</div>
</div>
```

Demo: https://codepen.io/jcubic/pen/wvwJNqQ?editors=0110

Comment: Thanks for the answer but my code has the drop and drop area dependency as well, all the directives are interlinked , if I want to go by your implementation then I'll have to implement the drop and grey area boundary(directives) as well , it would be really helpful if you could suggest how your resize directive I can fit in my existing code

Comment: @Enthu Just look at the code, you should not ask to write whole code for you. Here you have solution, handler for drag & drop. use selector inside the box not the whole box. If you want to be programmer you need to know how to incorporate solution in your own code. If you don't, then you will not be able to find any solution, to any problem because it will be little bit different then yours. There is probably lot of tutorial and article that show how to use everything you need. You just need to write them all in one code.

Comment: Bad implementation. If you have a list of draggable with 100 elements, the document:mouseup in every element make that the queue of event is satured and the navigator starts to have with lagging.

Comment: @Antoniodelamata if you know better implementation that will work with so many elements, you can write your own answer.

Answer (score 0):

One small hack you can do is add `'resizing'` class to the element in resize directive and check whether that class is present in draggable directive if present do not make it draggable. I can't get your code because it's so difficult. I don't know why you made this so complex.

Comment: Because I had to handle drag and drop and to maintain bounding area of the dropzone, I think what u r suggwstung makes sense, I can help you with understanding what is happening there of you can tweak the existing stackblitz link it would be great thanks, I have explained step by step above

Comment: So for drag and drop there is draggable and droppable directive and movable and movable area directive are for maintaining the boundaries within dropzone directive of the grey area and all these directive communicate via droppable service so these are the 6 directives being used and then I have added Resize directive which also listens to mousemove and mouseup

Comment: It might look like a lot but all the directives are basically listening to mousedown, mousemove, mouseup :), so I had also tried same in the line as what you suggested in Draggable directive because it has dragstart output event emiiter which in the post at the top in the child div (dragstart) is being used,so inside the dragstart function in Draggable directive I was trying to check for the resizing class and was trying to stop the drag effect when resize class is there but it wasn't working but you are suggesting to check this on Resizable directive, hope now you can help me, thanks

Comment: @Enthu You can make it happen better since you know your code better, just add Hostbinding-class for resizing whenever resizing border clicked and check whether class resizing is present in draggable directive.

Comment: add a class named 'resizing' and check that class in draggable directive

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/199400/discussion-between-enthu-and-akhi-akl).

Comment: I had applied host binding class and placed checks in resizable and draggbale directive but when I debug I do not see the class present in dom

Comment: The reason I am not able to check for host binded resizing class in draggable directive is, at very first the draggable directive mousedown is triggered  and all the subsequent mousedown functions of rest of the directives after that only resizable mousedown is triggered , what way this can be handled then